# Installing Nvidia CUDA - dpkg and apt-get stuck in install process

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, cuda

I was trying to install Nvidia CUDA, in this process `gce-compute-image-packages` has become `installed` but not `post install configured`. I have tried following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a           # this only get stuck in the processing stage of gce...
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken  # tells me to run above.
sudo apt-get -f install            # gives above answer.
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock # doesn't solve anything above problems reoccur.
```

Removing lock files just restarts the above process.

After editing `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and removing the `gce-compute-image-packages` this section reapears after I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all gce-compute-image-packages
```

This command gets stuck in pre-removal script.

I am at loss of what to do! Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/gce-compute-image-packages.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Looks like this worked, so far.